# IOS App delay in loading sounds and images

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have created an IOS game using sprite kit and swift. The game contains sounds and images. The problem I am having is that once the game loads and I tap on a button which triggers the sound for tapping a button, The game freezes for about 1-2 seconds and then resumes and plays the sound just fine. This only happens one time per running the game, once it unfreezes the game runs smooth and plays sounds just fine. Is there any way around this so that the game will run smooth from the beginning? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: yes, by preloading the sound. If you use playSound action crutch, scrap that and go with an actual game audio engine, ie objectal

Comment: Im sorry but Im new to programming Im not sure what you mean by playSound action crutch, is there any way you could elaborate? or show me some code example?

Comment: It seems playSound was added to have *at least some way* to trigger a sound effect. It really can't do anything but, and therefore you can't really use it to program all audio needed for a game, unless you really only need a "tap tap tap" sound whenever the user touches something and definitely no music. Anything more, and you'll need to use either AVAudioPlayer (not optimized for playing many small sounds in quick succession) or a *proper* audio engine like ObjectAL.